# Where does the left hobo's head come from at 0:18

Tags: part-identification

I identified the right one (Emperor Palpatine), but I can't find the left one's head. Any help?
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=befr11mPESE

Comment: It says the video doesn't exist, so it's not possible to see the minifigs you are referring to.

Comment: Does this work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=befr11mPESE? Apparently someone edited my question and broke the URL.

Comment: Yes, that works. My answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be this minifig, but the face is further customized with a marker. If you look at the eyebrows and the eyebags they have the same lines. But the mouth and nose and painted over, and the hair is darkened as well: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpx109&in=M